# Rest API issue in cart : multiple store only shows default store's price of a product in cart for both store in magento2.1.7

Tags: magento2, cart, api, rest-api

In my multi store Using here same magento2 default API calls to POST and GET cart items, However am getting only default price of a product for both english and arabic store.ALL other product up to product list API I got different prices for different stores there am used just 'store_code' after '/rest/' in API calls.

Expected Result : Price should be different for different stores products in cart.

Actual Result : Only getting default store's price of a product in both english and arabic stores in magento2.1.7.

Comment: Some one is there to help on this.?